# What is the best way to extract data from this JSON string?

Tags: java, api, okhttp, unirest

I have been trying to figure out how to extract the values from this api call that returns a JSON string. I've read countless examples but nothing seems to match my case closely enough that I'm able to figure it out.
The JSON is formatted like this:

```
{2 items
  "type":"array"
  "items":{2 items
      "type":"object"
      "properties":{6 items
           "confirmed":{1 item
           "type":"integer"
           }
           "critical":{1 item
           "type":"integer"
           }
           "deaths":{1 item
           "type":"integer"
           }
           "lastChange":{2 items
           "type":"string"
           "format":"date-time"
           }
           "lastUpdate":{2 items
           "type":"string"
           "format":"date-time"
           }
           "recovered":{1 item
           "type":"integer"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

And my OkHttp request looks like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url("https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/totals?format=json")
.get()
.addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com")
.addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "my-api-key")
.build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I think the issue is that the first item in the JSON is an array. Within the array is an object which contains the properties. So far I have tried using Unirest and OkHttp.

This is how I was trying to access the data fields:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String respJson = response.body().string();
JsonParser jparse = new JsonParser();
JsonObject job = (JsonObject)(jparse.parse(respJson));
```

But I get the error code

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonArray cannot be cast to 
com.google.gson.JsonObject
```

I am confused. Do I need to create a JSONObject from the string, or a JSONArray?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Sorry, this is the actual response body:

```
[1 item
  0:{6 items
    "confirmed":15270765
    "critical":63634
    "deaths":624093
    "lastChange":"2020-07-22T19:54:49+02:00"
    "lastUpdate":"2020-07-22T20:00:04+02:00"
    "recovered":9207832
  }
]
```

And when I print the response.body().string();

```
[{"confirmed":23841926,"recovered":16361473,"critical":61767,"deaths":823389,"lastChange":"2020-08-25T02:11:37+02:00","lastUpdate":"2020-08-25T02:15:03+02:00"}]
```

Comment: This is not valid json, check using jsonlint.com

Comment: square brackets means it is an array.